# dnu pack ignores project *.nuspec file

Tags: asp.net-core

In an ASP.NET 5 project, I made a `*.nuspec` file for my project but `dnu pack` ignores it and produces a package without the metadata I supplied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dnu pack` uses the `project.json` file to create the package. The nuspec file is not used.

So fill out your project.json file similar to this

```
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"description": "My awesome library",
"authors": [ "fiat" ],
"tags": [ "widget" ],
"projectUrl": "https://github.com/username/foobar",
"licenseUrl": "",
"iconUrl": "",
```

etc